# jQuery UI, Droppable - Why this doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

This is very simple ... drag and drop in area. But when i set **margin** to dragged element (.a1_73, .a2_73) nothing happend on dropped area. Seriously I have no idea why. What is wrong ??? Without margin all works greate.

**HTML**

```
<div id="a1_73" class="empty">#A1</div>
<div id="a2_73" class="empty">#A2</div>
<div id="a3_73" class="empty">#A3</div>
<div id="a4_73" class="empty">#A4</div>

<div class="a1_73 dragme">.A1</div>
<div class="a2_73 dragme">.A2</div>
<div class="a4_73 dragme">.A3</div>
<div class="a3_73 dragme">.A4</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".dragme").draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).put_element();
    }
});

$.fn.put_element = function () {
    $this = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    $this = $this[0];
    $("#" + $this + "").droppable({
        accept: "." + $this + "",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert('OK');
        }
    })
}
```

***CSS***

```
        #a1_73 {
        width: 362px;
        height: 295px;
        margin-left: 748px;
        margin-top: 314px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #a2_73 {
        width: 318px;
        height: 213px;
        margin-left: 421px;
        margin-top: 188px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #a3_73 {
        width: 360px;
        height: 243px;
        margin-left: 23px;
        margin-top: 367px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #a4_73 {
        width: 396px;
        height: 199px;
        margin-left: 19px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .a1_73 {
        margin: 162px 0px 0px 858px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .a2_73 {
        margin: 97px 0px 0px 759px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .a4_73 {
        margin: 33px 0px 0px 634px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .a3_73 {
        margin: 231px 0px 0px 853px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    div {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .dragme {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzmh00te/)

RK

Comment: Please post a snippet (use the button on the editor) instead of a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: any errors ? what should happen ? Where is your Question ?

Comment: No erros, simply doesen't work at all.

Comment: Whick $(this) you planed to use in your draggable .. In logically how droppable element know the draggable one before you make it droppable? .. please try to read [Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) to use that in a right way.. Good luck

Comment: Drag and drop actions works greate before adding margin to dragging element. Problem appears when I want set dragging element on page using margin left/top.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

try this.

HTML

```
<div id="a1_73" class="empty">#A1</div>
<div id="a2_73" class="empty">#A2</div>
<div id="a3_73" class="empty">#A3</div>
<div id="a4_73" class="empty">#A4</div>

<div class="a1_73 dragme">.A1</div>
<div class="a2_73 dragme">.A2</div>
<div class="a3_73 dragme">.A3</div>
<div class="a4_73 dragme">.A4</div>
```

JS

```
$(".dragme").draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).put_element();
        }
    });

    $.fn.put_element = function () {
        $this = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        $this = $this[0];
        $("#" + $this + "").droppable({
            accept: "." + $this + "",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                alert('OK');
            }
        })
    }
```

CSS

```
    #a1_73 {
    width: 362px;
    height: 295px;
    margin-left: 748px;
    margin-top: 314px;
    position: absolute;
}
#a2_73 {
    width: 318px;
    height: 213px;
    margin-left: 421px;
    margin-top: 188px;
    position: absolute;
}
#a3_73 {
    width: 360px;
    height: 243px;
    margin-left: 23px;
    margin-top: 367px;
    position: absolute;
}
#a4_73 {
    width: 396px;
    height: 199px;
    margin-left: 19px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
.a1_73 {

    position: absolute;
}
.a2_73 {

    position: absolute;
}
.a4_73 {

    position: absolute;
}
.a3_73 {

    position: absolute;
}
div {
    background-color: red;
}
.dragme {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but You just remove margins from element.

Comment: Yes, it's working but I need margin set and You just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

So, I put all .a1_73, .a2_73, .a3_73, .a4_73 into a DIV.holder, move holder to right, change margin to smaller of each element inside and it's works.

Margin of .a1_73, .a2_73, .a3_73, .a4_73 cant be higher than 100px.